# How to find Top n topics for a document

Tags: information-retrieval, tf-idf, lda, topic-modeling, top-n

I am using the tf - IDF to rank terms in a document. When terms are arranged in descending order of the tf - IDF, top 'n' terms are most relevant to that document.
When we choose a document, top 'n' terms of that document has to be displayed.
My question is how to decide the value of 'n'?
For example: for a document terms arranged in descending order of the tf - IDF is as follows:

Document 1

1. president

   2. Obama
   3. Barak
   4. speech
   5. inauguration
   6. come
   7. the
   8. look
   9. again
   10. took

Now when I want to show topics for document 1, I need only top 5 terms, since all others are not relevant or not topics for the document.
How do I decide this breaking point of terms in a document?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In relation to your sample data, there seems to be a problem because 6 to 10 are non-informative stop-words, some of them even stop-words, such as 'the'.

So, a first step that you should try is to remove stop-words.

Coming back to your question, there is no best practice for choosing the value of K in a top-K keyword extraction. This varies from one document to another because some documents are more informative (often multi-topical) than others, which means that these documents should have a higher value of K.

A way to decide on a stopping point is to check the relative differences between the tfidf values between consecutive terms and then stop at a point where this relative difference becomes higher than a threshold, which indicates that there is a big fall in the amount of key informtion that you are outputting.

Assuming that you have computed a tfidf score for each term and have sorted them in descending order of their values, compute the following
before adding every new term

[image]

If the above expression is true, where delta is a pre-defined threshold, add the new term... because the new term's informativeness measure is *close-enough* to the ones already in the list. Otherwise stop if the expression is false, i.e. the difference is higher than delta.

A note: You can play around with different term scoring functions... not just tfidf.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Can you please suggest what are the other scoring functions? (Other than tf-idf)

Thanks

Comment: There're a number of other scoring functions that you can use - i) language modeling weighting of terms, ii) BM25 weighting of terms, iii) other statistical approaches based on LDA to find out term importance... etc.

Comment: Will look at those methods.
Thanks